# C# MVC Razor namespace Microsoft.VisualBasic.Financial not resolving

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using MVC 3 Razor .cshtml pages.  I have included the Microsoft.VisualBasic reference into my project and use it just fine in existing web forms pages.  But within my view it will not resolve the Financial NameSpace.  It sees Microsoft.VisualBasic just fine but the only thing intellisense brings up is Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities and Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider. Attempting to use Financial results in a compile error of:

The type or namespace name 'Financial' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.VisualBasic'

Any help is greatly appreciated i need to use the NPV function under financial.

Answer (score 0):

The type is [in the Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.financial.aspx), make sure you have a reference to that to be able to use it in Razor.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just creating a static Finance class that i can make calls to that have access to that namespace.  This of course ends up being more reusable anyway.